# Pour {in/on/onto/into/over} my cup

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Please, pour the wine _____ my cup.
>
> a) **in**  b) **on** c) **onto** d) **into**  e) **over**

which preposition would be appropriate here in the gap?

Comment: Which one(s) would you eliminate? Does "into" and "onto" have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

A cup is normally hollow and concave, it is usually used for containing liquid, if we were to compare it to a pool, choosing the most suitable answer in the OP's question should become clear

1. Kim jumped ***on / onto*** the pool  (NO)
   *Water is not a hard solid surface.*
2. Kim jumped ***on*** the springboard (YES)
   *A springboard has a solid surface.*
3. Kim ran and jumped ***onto*** the [springboard](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/springboard) (YES)
   *“onto” expresses the movement*
4. Kim jumped ***in*** the pool. (YES)
   *this suggests that Kim was already in the water.*
5. Kim ***played in*** the pool with their friends. (YES)
6. Kim jumped ***into*** the pool (YES)
   *This tells us that Kim was outside of the water; “into“ expresses the idea of movement*
7. Kim jumped **over** the pool (POSSIBLE)
   *This suggests that Kim leaped from one side of the pool to the other, it might be possible if the pool was a small children's [paddling pool](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paddling-pool)*

Thus the most suitable answer is d)

> Please, pour the wine **into** my cup.